# Sub-process Error

Tags: debian-wheezy, dpkg

Im trying to move my Wordpress site from a managed VPS to my OVH dedicated machine and im in the middle of trying to install WP.
However following [these instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/WordPress#Basic_Installation_guide_for_Wheezy) I get this error:

`Setting up exim4-daemon-light (4.80-7+deb7u1) ...
[....] Starting MTA:2015-07-04 22:33:53 Exim configuration error in line 38 of /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp:
  main option "acl_smtp_mime" unknown
Invalid new configfile /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp, not installing 
/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp to /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
invoke-rc.d: initscript exim4, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing exim4-daemon-light (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 exim4-daemon-light
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

I've found a few relevant questions but they didn't solve my problem.

I am running Wheezy if that helps.

Comment: I think I may have fixed it with the following:
`apt-get --assume-yes --purge remove exim4-daemon-light sa-exim`

Comment: You can put that into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get install exim4-daemon-heavy`

That's what fixed it for me, because simply commenting the line out does not help when reinstalling exim4, as the file get's simply regenerated and the uncommenting overwritte.

A bit late but maybe usefull for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix: comment this line out using a `#` sign, and then re-run your command. I do not suppose you need this option at all, but if you do, you might want to fiddle with it later on.